# population change

Tags: algebra-precalculus

According to the 2000 U.S. Census, the U.S. total population was 281,421,906. The 2010 Census indicated the total population was 308,745,538. What was the percent change in the U.S. population from 2000 to 2010? Round your answer to the nearest tenth of a percent

Answer (score 2):

Percentage increase is $\dfrac {\text{new-old}}{\text{old}}\times 100\%$

Answer (score 2):

$$281,421,906+(p/100)281,421,906=308,745,538.$$

Comment: Nice Adi! Thanks for the Edit

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Percent change over time}\;
=\;\frac{\text{(most recent) - (former)}}{\text{former}}\times 100\%\quad\quad$$

Applied to your problem, compute the following:
$$\text{Percent change in population}\; 
=\; \frac{308,745,538 - 281,421,906}{281,421,906} \times 100\% \; = \;\;?$$